# How do I determine what price to lower my widgets to so that it is not over the average of the competitor?

Tags: percentages

Here is a real world business equation that am having problems solving around a product pricing structure.  Below is list of the widget prices. I need to reduce that pricing by the % over average pricing of our competitors.  Appreciate any help.
How do I determine what price to lower my widgets to so that it is not over the average of the competitor? 
What is the equation to calculate this?

```
$110 - 24.09% over the average price of competitor
$135 - 41.77% over the average price of competitor
$199 - 56.93% over the average price of competitor
$260 - 63.37% over the average price of competitor
$395 - 69.16% over the average price of competitor
$520 - 70.03% over the average price of competitor
$700 - 72.91% over the average price of competitor
```

Answer (score 0):

If your price is $110$ and you are $24.09\%$ above the competitor, you are charging $1.2409$ times what the competitor is charging and he is charging $\frac {110}{1.2409}\approx 83.50$.  Your data is inconsistent.  If you do the same calculation for the other lines you get rather different values.